No se me abre el cuadro de diálogo con JOptionPane (JAVA)
Este es el código, no me da ningún error pero a la hora de ejecutar el programa no ocurre nada, no aparece ninguno de los cuadros de diálogo. Utilizo Eclipse.
import javax.swing.*;

public class Entrada_Ejemplo2 {



public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String nombre=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce tu nombre");
        
        String edad=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce tu edad");       
        // Para transformarlo a int, ya que se trata de un número usaremos el método parseInt():
        
        int edad_usuario=Integer.parseInt(edad);
        
        System.out.println("Hola " + nombre + " el año que viene tendrás " + (edad_usuario+1) + " años.");
        
    }
}


¡Gracias por la ayuda!
Terminé encontrando la solución por mi cuenta, parece ser que el programa estaba tratando de acceder a una clase de un módulo al que no tiene acceso.
En este caso, estaba tratando de acceder a la clase javax.swing.JOptionPane desde la clase Entrada_Ejemplo2, pero parece que el módulo en el que estaba el programa no tenía acceso al módulo java.desktop, donde se encuentra la clase JOptionPane.
Agregué requires java.desktop en el archivo module-info.java del directorio raíz y después de eso ya me funcionaba correctamente.

¡Gracias por la ayuda!
Terminé encontrando la solución por mi cuenta, parece ser que el programa estaba tratando de acceder a una clase de un módulo al que no tiene acceso.
En este caso, estaba tratando de acceder a la clase javax.swing.JOptionPane desde la clase Entrada_Ejemplo2, pero parece que el módulo en el que estaba el programa no tenía acceso al módulo java.desktop, donde se encuentra la clase JOptionPane.
Agregué requires java.desktop en el archivo module-info.java del directorio raíz y después de eso ya me funcionaba correctamente.

Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
